# How to assign keys to the values in jmeter when the list of values are output and store it in a mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, api, jmeter

[image]

It is showing keys here like `Price_1`, `Price_2`, etc... In debug sampler but not keys when iam storing in mongo only values are getting how to assign and store in mongo thanxs in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot doesn't give any clue with regards to why your "Write to DB" sampler failed, we need to see the configuration of this sampler and a screenshot of the `Sampler result` tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener focused on the `Write to DB` sampler.

In the meantime you can check out [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/), it has nice code examples for reading/writing data from/to MongoDB.